# How to get dimensions of a connected Android Wear device for making bitmaps smaller?

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-data-api

I would like to resize large images for connected Android Wear device. I don't want to transmit large images over Bluetooth. Is there some generic way? I don't want to hardcode screen size for a specific device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/creating.html#AddWearableFeatures) states, that the background images should be 640x400px if you want parallax effect or 400x400px if you don't want it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want such kind of optimizations you can ask particular device for a configuration (resolution etc.)
For the communication you can use one of WearableApi:
https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/index.html

Either [DataApi](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/data-items.html) or [MessageApi](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/messages.html).

But I think you should use `MessageApi` in that case.
You will need to send a configuration from **Watch** to your **Phone** and then store it on **Phone**. From my test I can tell that `nodeId` appears to be constant [confirmation needed] - even after reboots. Your **Phone** will need to ask for the configuration only once and store this configuration (associated to sender's `nodeId`) for later use.
Then if you're about to send a bitmap to a connected `Node`, you need just  to read it's configuration (stored locally) and resize that bitmap to appropriate size:)

Comment: Thanks, I know about this manual way. I was wondering if there is something baked in into the framework. I have a feeling that I saw it somewhere during I/O talk/video, but I can't find it.

Comment: I cannot recall anything like that from Google I/O :( I think there is no such thing. However I think it's not a big deal when `nodeId` appears to be constant, so read once - use any time later.